# How to make fragment appear below TabLayout in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

In my **activity** I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/find_friend_fragment_container"
    tools:context="com.hb.birthpay.activity.FindFriendActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/find_friends_options_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my **fragment** I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             tools:context=".fragment.SuggestedFriendsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suggested friends"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:id="@+id/suggested_friend_text_view"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/suggested_friends_recycler_view"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/find_friend_progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I add the fragment dynamically within the activity code. Right now this is what it looks like:

[image]

I want my fragment to align below the TabLayout in the activity. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Change the outermost `<RelativeLayout` to a `<LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks @Vucko! You should right your answer below.

Comment: No problem. Will do. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating my comment to the answers since it helped fix it:

> Change the outermost `<RelativeLayout` to a `<LinearLayout`.

Short explanation: Using `<RelativeLayout>` allows for overlapping, which is not the case with `<LinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 2):

add into a new framelayout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/find_friend_fragment_container"
>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/find_friends_options_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/find_friends_options_tab_layout"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainAcitivity:

```
transation.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
```